# How do you check an items attribute and swap it for an image using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, attributes

I have a list of items, each having an attribute containing a list of locations.

What I would essentially like to do is some type of "if statement" (i assume) to check of the "container" attribute, swap out the text and replace it with an image.

So, if the container attribute reads "United Kingdom, Spain", I would like to say, if the container attribute equals "United Kingdom", remove the text and replace with an image of the UK flag. So if the attribute contains multiple locations, instead of text, it'll contain icons of each locations flag. For demonstration purposes, I have included the below;

```
$('.location.container').attr('location');
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by list? dropdown list?

Comment: Good question. To clarify, I have 20 "Location Containers" on the page, each containing different information. One piece of that information would be "Location" information. So by list, I was referencing many containers (divs) on the page. :)

Comment: Why not use `data-location`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:[Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ckjtJ)

**Html:**

```
<div class="location-container" Location="Spain">
  <div class="text-container">United Kingdom, Spain</div>
</div>

<div class="location-container" Location="United Kingdom">
  <div class="text-container">United Kingdom, Spain</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.location-container').each(function(){


  if( $(this).attr('Location').toString().indexOf("United Kingdom")!=-1) {
   $(this).find('.text-container').text(  
   $(this).find('.text-container').text().replace('United Kingdom','<img src="http://northcyprusfreepress.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/flag_icon_uk.gif"/>'));
 //   $(this).find('.text-//container').html($(thi//s).find('.text-container').text());


  }
if($(this).attr('Location').toString().indexOf("Spain")!=-1) {

  $(this).find('.text-container').text(  $(this).find('.text-container').text().replace('Spain','<img src="http://www.images2.welproma.com/spain_flag_icon.png"/>'));



  }
   $(this).find('.text-container').html($(this).find('.text-container').text());
});
```

Comment: This worked a charm. Thanks Slacker. Appreciated. Thanks to everyone who responded, appreciate your time and approaches. Actually learned alot looking at these examples.

Comment: Slacker, I did find one concern with this which you maybe able to help me with. If I have five "Location.Containers" on the page, one of which has an attribute that equals united kingdom, the 'listitemid' will be changed for them all, as there's no reference to the single container you are looking at. Each location container has the same DIV structure inside. Anyway for it to be specific to each location container? Thanks again :)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxcgH - Here's an example. Same div structure, different values for the Location attribute, but both are affected because the JS is looking at everything.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Slacker. You're great. - On a side note, how do we chat on this site? I'd like to contact you about something you wrote if that's fine with you?

Comment: Hi Tron, I have updated the code. Plz check this link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ckjtJ

Answer (score 0):

Try :

Jquery [Data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

HTML :

```
<span data-name = "United Kingdom" data-location = "Europe">XYZ</span>
<span data-name = "United States" data-location = "America">XYZ</span>
```

Javascript :

```
var location = $('.location.container').data('location');
//similarly also get name = $('.location.container').data('name'); 

if(location === "United Kingdom"){
//replace flag
}
else{
//retain flag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="location">
  <span class="text">United Kingdom</span>
</div>

$(".location").each{
  function(){
    var text = $(this).closest(".text");
    text.hide();
    var flagUrl = 'http://blabla/flags/' + text.text() + '.jpg'; 
    $(this).append('<img />').attr('src', flagUrl );
  }
}
```

You will also have to split 'text' in case of multiple locations, and iterate on them but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a map of countries to flags:

```
var flags = {
    "United Kingdom": "/images/uk.gif",
    "Spain": "/images/spain.gif"
}

$('.location.container').each(function() {
    var locations = $(this).attr('location').split(/,\s*/);

    for (var i = 0, n = locations.length; i < n; ++i) {
        $(this).append('<img src="' + flags[locations[i]] + '" />');
    }
});
```